# Split JavaScript string with conditions

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I can separate a string by comma (,) in JavaScript with split. My string is as follows:

```
"Hojas, DNI, Factura {Con N° de O/C impresa, otra cosa}, Pasaporte, Permiso"
```

The result should be:

```
["Hojas", "DNI", "Factura {Con N° de O/C impresa, otra cosa}", "Pasaporte", "Permiso"]
```

I tried to do the following:

```
"Hojas, DNI, Factura {Con N° de O/C impresa, otra cosa}, Pasaporte, Permiso".split(/,\s+(.+\s{.+})?/g)
```

But I get the following result: `["Hojas", "DNI, Factura {Con N° de O/C impresa, otra cosa}", "", undefined, "Pasaporte", undefined, "Permiso"]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Assuming that there are no unpaired or nested `{}`**, you can use a `(?![^{}]*})` look-ahead to make sure there is no closing `}` after the comma:

```
\s*,\s*(?![^{}]*})
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aE4gJ3/1)

And a snippet:

```js
var re = /\s*,\s*(?![^{}]*})/g; 
var str = 'Hojas, DNI, Factura {Con N° de O/C impresa, otra cosa}, Pasaporte, Permiso';
var res = str.split(re);
for (var i=0; i<res.length; i++) {
  document.write(res[i]+ "<br/>");
}
```

The `\s*` are used to trim the resulting array entries.

Answer (score 0):

Please find below code snippet:

```
var arr = "Hojas, DNI, Factura {Con N° de O/C impresa, otra cosa}, Pasaporte, Permiso".split(/\s*,\s*(?![^{}]*})/g);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: `Factura {Con N° de O/C impresa, otra cosa}` should be one element, but your code get two

Comment: @Grundy: Thanks. Corrected the same.