# How to split a string in javascript using the split() function

Tags: javascript, string, split

How can I split an object like `["text1 text2"]` to only show the `text1 text2` string in javascript?

Comment: `["text1 text2"]` is an Array, not a String.  It doesn't have a `split()` method

Comment: simple use your arrayname[0]. It will return text1 text2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split JavaScript string with conditions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33127397/split-javascript-string-with-conditions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Tibrogargan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2487517/tibrogargan) said in the comments above, `["text1 text2"]` is an array. This array contains one string value `"text1 text2"` which can be accessed either by using it's index inside an array (to get that specific item) or by looping through all the items inside the array (if you want all items).

For your case, it's easy to use index.

```
var stringArray = ["text1 text2"];
console.log(stringArray[0]);
// text1 text2 should be logged into console
```

Check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) for more documentation.

Answer (score 2):

You just want to access the value inside? `["text1 text2"][0]` would return the string, `text1 text2`